# Prove the sequence converges to 4

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $a_1 =2 , a_2=8, a_{2n+1} =\frac{a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}}{2}, a_{2n+2} =\frac{a_{2n}a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}}$ for all $n\ge 1.$

Then we have to prove that (for $a_n $ is a sequence): $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n =4$$

My attempt: we have $a_{2n+2}\le a_{2n+1}$

And by this we get $$a_4\le a_6 \le ... \le a_{2n+2}\le ... \le a_{2n+1} \le ... \le a_5 \le a_3$$

This shows that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n+2} = \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{2n+1}=x(say)$$

From this and the given data, how do we prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n =4$$

Comment: Just as a first point, Your first claim is wrong. Set $n = 0$ you have that $a_2 \le a_1$ but $a_2 = 8$ and $a_1 = 2$.

Comment: @Gregory n=0 is not a possibility.  I forgot to add it the conditions are all true only when $n\ge 1$. Those two given terms are expection for all that I've proved in my attempt so we neglect them in general case

Comment: @Gregory I think the inequality will hold eventually because AM-HM

Comment: Note that the string of inequalities does not automatically prove that the two sublimits are equal (consider $a_k = (-1)^{k-1} (1+1/k)$ for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second recurrence relation produces a telescoping product; indeed, one has :
$$
a_{2n} = \frac{a_{2n-3}}{a_{2n-1}}a_{2n-2} 
       = \frac{a_{2n-3}}{a_{2n-1}}\frac{a_{2n-5}}{a_{2n-3}}a_{2n-4} 
       = \ldots 
       = \frac{a_1a_2}{a_{2n-1}} 
       = \frac{16}{a_{2n-1}}
$$
Substituting this expression inside the other recurrence relation, one gets :
$$
a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}\right) 
         = \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{2n-1}+\frac{16}{a_{2n-1}}\right) 
$$
This recurrence relation for the odd-indexed elements has the advantage to be uncoupled/independent from the the even elements.

This well-known case can be solved explicitly by reparametrization, namely by setting $a_{2n+1} = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$, in order to study its limit. However, assuming that the odd-indexed subsequence converges, its limit will be a fixed point of the RHS, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n+1} = L = \frac{1}{2}\left(L+\frac{16}{L}\right)$, hence $L = 4$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n} = \frac{16}{L} = 4$ too, so that the original sequence converges towards $a_\infty = L = 4$.